# How to use async/await promises with React props/state?

Tags: reactjs, async-await

I'm trying to dynamically load properties into a React component. The properties are set in `this.props.customObjects` using `fetch` with `async/await` higher up in the component structure.

My `CustomObject` component (below) receives the properties in the form of a promise, but I fail in actually showing the fetched data in the component. I guess my component renders before the promise has resolved.

What's the best way to solve this? Can values from `async/await` be used in `props`, or do I have to use `state`?

My component:

```
export default class CustomObject extends React.Component {

    getCustomObject = (elementType) => {
        const customObject = this.props.customObjects[elementType];
        console.log('customObject', customObject);
        return customObject;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const customObject = this.getCustomObject(this.props.element.elementType)
        this.setState({ customObject });
    }

    render () {
        return <div className={this.props.className} style={this.props.style}>
            {this.state.customObject.name} // Gives TypeError: Cannot read property 'customObject' of null
        </div>
    }

}
```

The console log looks like:

[image: console.log]

Answer (score 3):

If it's a promise you can say something like:

```
customObject.then((result) => {
    this.setState({customObject: result})
})
```

As you're waiting for something, you need to use `setState` to get re-render. You should put in a fallback, in case the promise is still pending in your `render()` when it is first called.

Answer (score 2):

There is a couple of ways to handle your situation. One of them is if `this.getCustomObject(...)` is returning a Promise, you can wait for it to resolve and then set the state.

**For Example**

```
this.getCustomObject(this.props.element.elementType).then((customObject) => {
  this.setState({ customObject });
});
```

For more information about Promise please check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

This would not completely solve your problem if you don't give a default value for `this.state.customObject` since its gonna be undefined till the Promise resolved. You can use something like `{this.state.customObject ? this.state.customObject.name : 'Loading..'}`

Comment: Thanks! Is there an alternative to `then()` now when we have async/await?

Comment: Rather than waiting the promise resolve you can use `await` and run it is like a synchronous but I wouldn't suggest that unless you are really need to.